# Can we counter Vissicitude's effects by cutting off the affected limb then regenerating it?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade

A friend who knows I'm a big fan of the Tzimisce clan asked me how Vicissitude works. After I told her that it's permanent unless you are from a better generation (or you are a Nosferatu and used Vicissitude to cancel your curse), she said that it's super strong, then presented me with a situation:

> Let's say that I play a vampire of a high generation, and
>   a Tzimisce with a lower one uses Vicissitude on me to
>   make one of my arms useless. Can I cut my arm off from where the Vicissitude effect started and regenerate it from that point? Or is my arm forever useless until I find a friendly Tzimisce to cancel the effect?

My guess as an ST would be yes, at least for keeping the game fun, but I didn't find if RAW it's true or not. So, can you counter Vicissitude's effects by cutting off an affected limb then regenerating it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The basic rule is that any vampire can heal damage by spending blood points and return to the state in which they were during the Embrace, or shortly before it.

You can practically treat Vicissitude as something that can change this basic state if used by a vampire of a lower Generation, and not changing it otherwise. I will not quote the rule since you are already familiar with it.

If the basic state of your limb is that it has long sharp bone claws at the end, bad news for you. Your limb will regenerate but have the same claws again.

To put it another way, blood points return a vampire to the vampire's template. Vicissitude changes the template.

Plot-wise, that's the point of Vicissitude and the whole scariness of the Tzimisce clan. It wouldn't be as spooky if you could so easily get rid of the damage.

Comment: To put it another way, blood points return a vampire to the vampire's template. Vicissitude changes the template.